# Can't find the correct CSS selector for a price monitor with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to create my own price monitor using Scrapy but I can't seem to find a way to retrieve the price of a page using the CSS selector? What would be the best practice here? I can't get it via XPath either.

This is the page I'm having troubles with:
[Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/docker-mastery/)

It seems that the price is in a `<span>` without any class like:

```html
<span class>$129.99</span>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to use xpath at some point for this. First, even if the parent element does not have a class or id or something you can easily access, you can still use xpath to reach that span element. If you can reach the parent element you can then use the child:: tag to get the span element. Once you have the span element getText() will yield the price value.

The xpath you want will look something like this: `//div[@class='buy-box__element']//span[2]/span`